# pass generic type class to method

Tags: java, generics

I want to convert `List<Object[]>` to `List<ClassX>`

For that purpose, I have created a method:

```
public List mapObjectArrayListToClassList(List<Object[]> objectArrayList, Class genericType){
    //some awesome logic
    return new ArrayList<genericType>();
}
```

I want to call the method as follows:

```
mapObjectArrayListToClassList(objectArrayList, ClassX.class);
```

I am getting compilation error:

```
genericType cannot be resolved to a type
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Type arguments provided in generic type usages must be type names or type variables, they cannot be references to variables or expressions.

Make your method generic.

```
public <T> List<T> mapObjectArrayListToClassList(List<Object[]> objectArrayList, Class<T> genericType){
    //some awesome logic
    return new ArrayList<T>(); // or return new ArrayList<>(); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to specify the generic type for the method

```
 public <T> List<T> mapObjectArrayListToClassList(List<Object[]> objectArrayList, Class<T> genericType)
```

**Note:** Raw types like `List` and `Class` compile in Java but don't use them, they are evil.